# Hazelcast - Client mode - How to recover after cluster failure?

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We are using hazelcast distributed lock and cache functions in our products. Usage of  distributed locking is vitally important for our business logic.

Currently we are using the embedded mode(each application node is also a hazelcast cluster member). We are going to switch to client - server mode.

The problem we have noticed for client - server is that, once the cluster is down for a period, after several attempts clients are destroyed and any objects (maps, sets, etc.) that were retrieved from that client are no longer usable.
Also the client instance does not recover even after the Hazelcast cluster comes back up (we receive HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException )

I know that this issue has been addressed several times and ended up as being a feature request:

[issue1](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/4363)

[issue2](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/10135)

[issue3](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/9692)

My question : What should be the strategy to recover the client? Currently we are planning to enqueue a task in the client process as below. Based on a condition it will try to restart the client instance...
We will check whether the client is running or not via clientInstance.getLifecycleService().isRunning() check.

Here is the task code:

```
private class ClientModeHazelcastInstanceReconnectorTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            HazelCastService hazelcastService = HazelCastService.getInstance();
            HazelcastInstance clientInstance = hazelcastService.getHazelcastInstance();
            boolean running = clientInstance.getLifecycleService().isRunning();
            if (!running) {
                logger.info("Current clientInstance is NOT running. Trying to start hazelcastInstance from ClientModeHazelcastInstanceReconnectorTask...");
                hazelcastService.startHazelcastInstance(HazelcastOperationMode.CLIENT);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error occured in ClientModeHazelcastInstanceReconnectorTask !!!", ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Is this approach suitable? I also tried to listen LifeCycle events but could not make it work via events.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hazelcast 3.9 we changed the way connection and reconnection works in clients. You can read about the new behavior in the docs: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.1/manual/html-single/index.html#configuring-client-connection-strategy

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Hazelcast 3.10 you may increase connection attempt limit from 2 (by default) to maximum:

ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
   clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().setConnectionAttemptLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);